# Casperjs google auth popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, phantomjs, casperjs

The Problem: I am working on a Casperjs script that will log into an application. The application utilizes google auth. I am trying to simulate how a user would sign in, so going to the site, the user first clicks a Sign in with Google button which opens a new tab asking for google credentials. I have these pieces working... where I am stuck is when the user submits the google auth form the expectation is that the sign in tab closes and the original window recieves those credentials and allows the user into the application. If I take a screen shot after all these events I still remain on the original login page rather than gaining access to the app. My code is posted below:

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    waitTimeout: 5000,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
});

casper.capturePath = function(name) {
    return this.capture('./captures/' + name)
}

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
   this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

casper.on('popup.created', function() {
    this.echo("url popup created : " + this.getCurrentUrl(),"INFO");
});

casper.on('popup.loaded', function() {
    this.echo("url popup loaded : " + this.getCurrentUrl(),"INFO");
});

casper
    .start('<url>', function() {
        this
            .then(function() {
                this.clickLabel('Sign in with Google', 'button');
            })
            .waitForPopup(/accounts\.google/)
            .withPopup(/accounts\.google/, function(popup) {
                this
                    .fillSelectors('form#gaia_loginform', { '#Email': '<username>' }, false)
                    .thenClick('input#next')
                    .wait(500, function() {
                        this.waitForSelector('#Passwd',
                            function success() {
                                this
                                    .echo('success', 'INFO')
                                    .fillSelectors('form#gaia_loginform', { 'input[name=Passwd]': '<password>' }, false)
                                    .capturePath('beforeSubmit.png')
                                    .thenClick('input#signIn')
                                    .wait(500, function() {
                                        this.capturePath('afterSubmit.png');
                                    })
                                },
                                function fail() {
                                    this.echo('failure');
                                })
                    })
            })
    })
    .then(function() {
        this.waitForSelector('.dashboard-container',
            function success() {
                this
                    .echo('logged in!', 'INFO')
                    .capturePath('in.png')
            },
            function fail() {
                this
                    .capturePath('failed.png')
                    .echo('failed to login', 'ERROR');
            })
    })
.run();
```

When I get to the `this.waitForSelector('.dashboard-container',` line the script will timeout because it cannot find the selector I have told it to grab... presumably because it is not truly logging in the user. (Also the application is a React application incase thats important)

I have been spinning my wheels on this one for awhile, any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: What version of phantomJS/CasperJS are you using?

Comment: Any errors logged?

Comment: phantomjs: 2.1.1, casperjs: 1.1.3

Comment: `Page Error: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'Object.assign({}, state, { instant: [].concat(_toConsumableArray(state.instant), [action.data]) })')`, I think this error occurs because I am waiting for a selector it cannot find

Answer (score 1):

I think It works now. The problem was, that you tried to `this.waitForSelector('.dashboard-container',` actually outside of the popup, on the main page.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    waitTimeout: 5000,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4',
    viewportSize:{width: 1600, height: 900}
});
casper.capturePath = function(name) {
    return this.capture('./captures/' + name)
}

casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
   this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

casper.on('popup.created', function(newPage) {
this.echo("url popup created : " + this.getCurrentUrl(),"INFO");
newPage.viewportSize={width:1600,height:900}
});

casper.on('error', function(msg) {
this.echo('Error: ' + msg,"ERROR");
});// You have missed this callback!

casper.on('popup.loaded', function() {
    this.echo("url popup loaded : " + this.getCurrentUrl(),"INFO");
});

casper
    .start('http://domu-test-2/node/10', function() {
        this
            .wait(0,function() {// 'then(function' won't work as expected in any callback function.
                this.clickLabel('Sign in with Google', 'button');
            })
            .waitForPopup(/accounts\.google/)
            .withPopup(/accounts\.google/, function(popup) { 
                this
                    .fillSelectors('form#gaia_loginform', { '#Email': 'luxadm1' }, false)
                    .thenClick('input#next')
                    .wait(700, function() {
                        this.waitForSelector('#Passwd',
                            function success() {
                                this
                                    .echo('success', 'INFO')
                                    .fillSelectors('form#gaia_loginform', { 'input[name=Passwd]': '<pass_here>' }, false)
                                    .capturePath('beforeSubmit.png')
                                    .thenClick('input#signIn')
                                    .wait(300, function() {// less than previous '.wait(700, function() {' -- otherwise will be buggy
                                        this.capturePath('afterSubmit.png');
                                    })
                                },
                                function fail() {
                                    this.echo('failure');
                                })
                    })
            })
    })
    .then(function(){//here outside of the popup!!
        this.withPopup(/accounts\.google/, function(popup){// we need to be here until the previous '.withPopup' function will switch to 'about:blank', otherwise we will get an error: 'CasperError: Couldn't find popup with url matching pattern'
        this
       /*.wait(3000,*/ .waitForSelector('div.sPxS6d',//'.dashboard-container' -- i've not seen such selector there  
            function success() {
                this
                    .echo('logged in!', 'INFO')
                    .capturePath('in.png')
            },
            function fail() {
                this
                    .capturePath('failed.png')
                    .echo('failed to login', 'ERROR');
            })
    });})
.run();
```